# How to make scroll track a moving div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do you force the window to scroll so that a specific div is always in view? Ie track the div as it moves.

I want to keep a div in the centre of the screen as it moves left or right (and prevent scrolling away from this.

See example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JosephByrne/7hyqvtre/) - I want the viewing window to automatically follow the character as you move off the screen to the right, and not let you scroll left or right so you always have the character in view.

I tried using:

```
body {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

and this prevents scrolling away from the div but the div is not centred in the screen but off to the side.

Comment: maybe youre looking for `div { position:fixed }`

Comment: But I want to div to remain in the centre of the window as it moves, defining it as `fixed` doesn't do that

Comment: it usualy goes in the opposite way: the character stays on the center of the screen, while the background moves on.